# Why is in Android, getDeclaredMethod available on API level 9 only?

Tags: java, android, reflection

In Android, method `getDeclaredMethod` on class `Class` is said to be available starting on API Level 9 ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E...%29)). How is that possible? It has been available since JDK 1.1 ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-)). Should I believe what the Android docs says?

Comment: Because Android is not pure Java? From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API), *"Dalvik does not align to Java SE nor Java ME class library profiles (e.g., Java ME classes, AWT or Swing are not supported). Instead it uses its own library built on a subset of the Apache Harmony Java implementation."*. So it's up to Google to decide which is included or not. That's just my 2 cents, since I don't really know much more about it.

Answer (score 0):

The information its Ok, you are right. Android API 9 and Java JDK 1.1, but Remember Android have some changes in methods and class, also come times you need to call Java class or Android class with the similar name but diferentes arguments or methods, operations, results, etc.

For example you have 2 util

```
import android.util.*;
import java.util.*;
```

Depends what you need.